# How to avoid unwanted transactions and locks using FireDAC and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

From analyzing table locks in SQL Server, my Win32 application built in RAD Studio XE7 starts numerous transactions while each FDQuery is active. Sometimes this causes application problems and locks with dozens of users. Especially with triggered tables.

For my test, I used simple FDConnection and FDQuery as `Select * from Customer` with default settings, and concluded that `FDQuery1.Active:=True` causes the start of a Customer table transaction. The transaction disappears when `FDQuery1.Active:=false`.

I would like to inhibit the starting of transactions in FDQuery for read-only, as lists of data for grid or reports.

But I can't find a way to find the appropriate tuning of FDQuery.

Comment: Adjusting the settings of SQL Server so readers don't  block writers is the easiest. It produces more load on storage but using row versioning instead of locking for readers gets rid of a lot of deadlocks. Read up on READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT. Most other databases use this method.

Comment: Thanks Brian. However I can not consider the property TFDConnection.TxOptions.xiShapShot in conjunction with the SQL Server setting you mentioned, as the database is too large and many users work at the same time.
In this situation, I'd like a suggestion to adjust the properties of component FDQuery, in order to get query without lock.

Comment: Don't use FireDAC with SQL server. Use "native" ADO (dbGO) components instead. I do this. It's just a suggestion. Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server does not implement versioning of data blocks. So, to return a consistent set of rows, it guarantee that no other sessions makes changes do data during execution of a query, using shared locks.

Using "WITH(NOLOCK)" disable shared locks, but can result in an inconsistent result set.

The only one solution is to use READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT isolation level, which store changed data to temp, used to return consistent result sets without locking updates.

Answer (score 0):

For your FDConnection (or FDQuery) try to set FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll instead fmOnDemand,which keeps locking records in the table after the select is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the NOLOCK keyword for tables. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/

Comment: I tried doing `select * from Customers with (NOLOCK)`. But the transaction was created anyway. FireDAC probably starts an implicit transaction before.